# Serialize and deserialize an object (There is an error in XML document (0, 0).)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, encoding

I am trying to serialize and then deserialize an object. Serialization works ok, but deserialization throws a

```
System.InvalidOperationException : There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
  ----> System.Xml.XmlException : Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

The serialized xml looks OK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Data xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Id="1" Status="OK" xmlns="http://biz.si/Project/v0100/Data.xsd">
    <DataGroup Type="SomeType">AAEC</DataGroup>
</Data>
```

The encoding is utf-16, which is OK, but I suspect there is an encoding problem during deserialization. Now the code is running in test environment (unit tests) but the serialized xml will be sent to a web service.

This is my code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Foobar
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var d = new Data
        {
            Id = "1",
            Status = "OK",
            DataGroup = new DataGroup
            {
                Type = "SomeType",
                Value = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 }
            }
        };

        var serialized = Serialize(d);
        var deserialized = Deserialize(serialized);    // exception is thrown here.

        Debug.WriteLine("ok");
    }

    private XmlNode Serialize(Data data)
    {
        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
        StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
        {
            xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, data);
            var xml = sww.ToString();
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
            return xmlDocument;
        }
    }

    private Data Deserialize(XmlNode xmlData)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlData.InnerText));
        return (Data)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.demo.com", IsNullable = false)]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Data
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DataGroup")]
    public DataGroup DataGroup { get; set; }
}

[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class DataGroup
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText(DataType = "base64Binary")]
    public byte[] Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here: `InnerText` is not the property you want. It's not XML at all; look at it in the debugger. Second, don't use `MemoryStream`; wherever you got that one, he was just trolling you. `StringReader` is much easier to get working.

```
private Data Deserialize(XmlNode xmlData)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
    using (var stream = new StringReader(xmlData.OuterXml))
    {
        return (Data)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience .NET XML serialization does not like it or allow you to serialize a class without a parameter less constructor, but you see to be able to.  Below is how I do all my XML serialization.  I ran your classes and both serialize and deserialize work fine.  You can tweak it to your needs.  My test code is after the class code.

```
  [XmlRoot( Namespace = "http://biz.si/Project/v0100/Data.xsd", IsNullable = false )]
  [XmlType( AnonymousType = true )]
  public class sventevitData
  {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement( "DataGroup" )]
    public DataGroup DataGroup { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="sventevitData"/> class.
    /// Parameterless constructor required for .NET XML serialization
    /// </summary>
    public sventevitData(){}

    public void SerializeData( String FileWithPath )
    {
      try
      {
        using( Stream stream = new FileStream(  FileWithPath,     FileMode.Create, 
                                                FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write ) )
        {
          //  Serialize into the storage medium
          XmlSerializer xmlserial = new XmlSerializer( typeof( sventevitData ) );
          xmlserial.Serialize( stream, this );
          stream.Close();
        }
      }
      catch( Exception ex )
      {
        string msg  = ex.Message;
        ex = ex.InnerException;

        while( ex != null )
        {
          msg += "" + ex.Message;
          ex = ex.InnerException;
        }

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( 
          String.Format( "Exception writing sventevitData {0}: {1}", 
                          FileWithPath, msg ) );
      }
    }


    public static sventevitData DeserializeData( String FileWithPath )
    {
      sventevitData tmp;
      Stream stream;

      try
      {
        // Read the file back into a stream
        if( !File.Exists( FileWithPath ) )
        {
          DirectoryInfo di = null;

          if( !Directory.Exists( Path.GetDirectoryName( FileWithPath ) ) )
          {

            AddDirSecurity( Path.GetDirectoryName( FileWithPath ),
                            System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name,
                            FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow );

            di = Directory.CreateDirectory( Path.GetDirectoryName( FileWithPath ) );
          }

          AddDirSecurity( FileWithPath, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name,
                              FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow );

          File.Create( FileWithPath );
        }

        using( stream = new FileStream( FileWithPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read ) )
        {
          // Now create a binary formatter
          XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( sventevitData ) );
          stream = new FileStream( FileWithPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read );
          tmp = ( sventevitData )xmlserializer.Deserialize( stream );
          stream.Close();

          // Deserialize the object and use it
          return tmp;
        }
      }
      catch( Exception ex )
      {
        string msg  = ex.Message;
        ex = ex.InnerException;

        while( ex != null )
        {
          msg += "" + ex.Message;
          ex = ex.InnerException;
        }

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( String.Format( "Exception reading {0}: {1}", FileWithPath, msg ) );
      }

      return new sventevitData();
    }


    private static void AddDirSecurity(     String Dir, 
                                            String Account,
                                            FileSystemRights Rights,
                                            AccessControlType AccessType )
    {
      // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
      DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo( Dir );

      // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
      // current security settings.
      DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

      // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
      dSecurity.AddAccessRule( new FileSystemAccessRule( Account, Rights, AccessType ) );

      // Set the new access settings.
      dInfo.SetAccessControl( dSecurity );
    }
  }

  [XmlType( AnonymousType = true )]
  public class DataGroup
  {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText( DataType = "base64Binary" )]
    public byte[] Value { get; set; }
  }

[TestClass]
  public class sventevitDataTest
  {
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory( "StackOverflow" )]
    public void SerializeTest()
    {
      string fileWithPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;
      fileWithPath        = Path.Combine( fileWithPath, "testData.xml" );

      sventevitData data = new sventevitData();

      data.Id         = "1";
      data.Status     = "OK";
      data.DataGroup  = new DataGroup()
      {
        Type    = "SomeType",
        Value   = new byte[]{ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02 }
      };

      data.SerializeData( fileWithPath );
    }


    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory( "StackOverflow" )]
    public void DeserializeTest()
    {
      string fileWithPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;
      fileWithPath        = Path.Combine( fileWithPath, "testData.xml" );

      sventevitData data = sventevitData.DeserializeData( fileWithPath );
    }
  }
```

Forgot to include the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sventevitData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Id="1" Status="OK" xmlns="http://biz.si/Project/v0100/Data.xsd">
  <DataGroup Type="SomeType">AAEC</DataGroup>
</sventevitData>
```

Comment: A C# class with no defined constructor has a default constructor, which is parameterless (granting funny cases where a base class has no public parameterless constructor). This is why he "seems able to" serialize a class that "seems" not to have a parameterless constructor. Notice that his `Test()` method creates an instance of `Data` *without any constructor parameters*: `var d = new Data {};`. That's a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the information Ed!  I love learning new things.